# Batch for convesion of all characters to ASCII immediately after text file is updated

Tags: file, text, parameters, watch

I would like to ask you for your help with script running on Windows 11 64bit PC.
There are 6 subsequent operations what I need from script to do.

1. Check if Test.txt file exists. If found then continue. If not found stop with Error msg.
2. Execute "iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII Test.txt > Test_ascii.txt"
3. Save actual saving time of Test.txt file to variable.
4. Permanently check if Test.txt was updated  (bad eg.: Wait 100msec. (max. 1 sec.))
5. If saving time of Test.txt was different then go to "2."
6. If saving time of Test.txt is the same go to "3."

CTRL+C do EXIT from script.

test.txt  is text-file with 20-120 characters.

I tried to start to solve this task with script below, but it is unfortunately does not function.
I tested external function sucessfuly but when added internal, then it was stopped. It also seems that I cannot declare variable by $ in Windows bat-script.

```
@ECHO OFF
:CheckForFile
IF EXIST "Test.txt" (
$timeMod = forfiles /M Test.txt /C "cmd /c echo @ftime
If NOT $timeMod == (forfiles /M Test.txt /C "cmd /c echo @ftime)
  {
  iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII Test.txt > Test_ascii.txt
  }
  start-sleep -Milliseconds 100
  goto :CheckForFile    )
echo The file Test.txt not found.
pause
exit
```

I need to know how can I declare variable and fill with @time value.
Maybe it also exists some better method how to check immediately that text-file was updated than to check and compare its @time. I tried to search "Win32 Directory Change Notifications API" unfortunately not found real functional solution.
Thank you very much for your help.
Best regards Tomas

Comment: I have no answer, no help, I am continue with solution of problem alone:

Answer (score 0):

I found final fully function solution.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Script for replacing diacritical characters when input file was updated

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
IF EXIST "test.txt" (
    
set "file=test.txt"
set "hash="
:loop1
set "newhash="
for /f %%a in ('certutil -hashfile "!file!" SHA256 ^| find /v ":"') do set "newhash=%%a"
if not defined hash set "hash=!newhash!"
if "!newhash!" neq "!hash!"     (
    set "hash=!newhash!"

REM  Continue only if file was updated   Code for file update:

    del Test_ascii.txt.txt
FOR /f "tokens=1,* delims=" %%b in (test.txt) do (
    set "line=%%b"
    set "line=!line:á=a!"
    set "line=!line:č=c!"
    set "line=!line:ď=d!"
    set "line=!line:é=e!"
    set "line=!line:ě=e!"
    set "line=!line:í=i!"
    set "line=!line:ň=n!"
    set "line=!line:ó=o!"
    set "line=!line:ř=r!"
    set "line=!line:š=s!"
    set "line=!line:ť=t!"
    set "line=!line:ú=u!"
    set "line=!line:ů=u!"
    set "line=!line:ý=y!"
    set "line=!line:Ž=Z!"
    set "line=!line:ž=z!"
    set "line=!line:Á=A!"
    set "line=!line:Č=C!"
    set "line=!line:Ď=D!"
    set "line=!line:É=E!"
    set "line=!line:Ě=E!"
    set "line=!line:Í=I!"
    set "line=!line:Ň=N!"
    set "line=!line:Ó=O!"
    set "line=!line:Ř=R!"
    set "line=!line:Š=S!"
    set "line=!line:Ť=T!"
    set "line=!line:Ú=U!"
    set "line=!line:Ů=U!"
    set "line=!line:Ý=Y!"
    echo !line!>>Test_ascii.txt
                                                  )
                                )
REM   End of update script

timeout /t 1 > NUL
goto loop1          )
        ECHO The source file test.txt was not found.
        pause
        exit
```

I think that this unique solution can help someone who needs any character conversion in a text file.

**ATTENTION:**
I had only one big problem with different encoding of non-ASCII characters in Windows Notepad (UTF-8) and in Windows cmd behaviour (probably CP852, not sure). I solved this problem by using HexaEditor for correction of non-ASCII characters in the text of this `.bat` file (e.g., `á` = `e1` in Hex).